# How can I print the results of a function call in a Struts 2 JSP?

Tags: jsp, struts2

How can I print a value in JSP page,which is returned by a method of a particular class?

I have the object of particular class in my action class:

```
private PageTools pagetools = new PageTools();
```

I need to print the value returned by `pageTools.getLoggedUserName()`.

`getLoggedUserName` method returns value of session variable which is available when printing in java class... But how can I print it in the JSP page (calling by that object)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your struts2 Action define one field as

```
private String loggedInUserName;
//getter and setter
```

then in action method

```
loggedInUserName= pageTools.getLoggedUserName();
```

Now in your jsp for disply, just write

```
<s:property value="loggedInUserName" />
```

Comment: ofcourse it works.. but actually i want to print the value directly by calling with that object from jsp... I have some other methods in that class like formatdate etc which has to be called from the jsp page itself.. thanks for your answer.. is there a way to do like that??

Comment: then use <s:property value="pagetools.loggedUserName"/>

Comment: loggedUserName is not getter of variable loggedUserName its my method name... if i have a method formatDate(Date dat){  } in that class how can i call that using that object from jsp

Comment: Please share more code of your jsp, action and pagetool class

Comment: @vipincp OGNL allows you to call arbitrary methods, with arbitrary parameters, from the `<s:property>` tag. Just call the method. Your original question should be edited to reflect your actual question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have getters and setters for `pagetools` then in jsp it is as simple as that 
`<s:property value="pagetools.loggedUserName"/>`.

Comment: i have getters and setters for pageTools.. still its not printing.. waht will be the reason...? and loggedUserName is not a variable to acces like this.. its a method in that class.. say public String getLoggedUserName()
{

return "something";
}

Comment: It does not matter if it is method. Read about ognl http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/ognl-basics.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
<s:property value="pagetools.getLoggedUserName()"/>
```